# Python Error message customization

Tags: python-2.7, traceback

I want to avoid some files and modules in the StackTrace of thrown python error message..

eg:

```
An error occured: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/snehasys/dotvim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/start_vdebug.py", line 31, in run
    self.runner.run()
  File "/Users/snehasys/dotvim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 160, in run
    self.open()
  File "/Users/snehasys/dotvim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 74, in open
    raise e
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Say: I want to avoid start_vdebug.py file in this listing because it is repeated so many times in other scenarios.
Please Guide.

Comment: This is no duplicate, My problem is to avoid some module names, not the raised line. that is explained in the other thread. Please go through and verify..